# How can i get output in oop program in php

Tags: php

This is my code. It is giving me an error. I am new in OOP in PHP, please help me regarding this particular issue.

Code as following:

```
<?php 
class myclass 
{
   var $name;
   //public $vari="this is my class ";
   public function setvalue($newval)
   {
       $this->$name=$newval;
   }
   public function getvalue()
   {
       return $this->name;

   }
}

$object= new myclaas;
$object->setvalue("usman");
echo $object->getvalue();
?>
```

Error as following:

```
Fatal error: Class 'myclaas' not found in E:\wamp\www\oops\myclass.php on line 19
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the two errors in your code.
You didn't type the class name properly when you instantiated the class.Your class name is myclass , But you typed the class name myclaas.

Your Code

```
 $object= new myclaas;
```

See the corrected line below.

```
 $object= new myclass;
```

When you access properties in a class using $this pseudo variable don't insert a dollar sign in front of the variable (In your code see the $ sign in $name , You don't need it).

Your code look like this

```
 $this->$name = $newval;
```

You need to change the code to

```
 $this->name = $newval;
```

Updated code

```
<?php 
class myclass 
{
   var $name;

   public function setvalue($newval)
   {
       $this->name=$newval;
   }
   public function getvalue()
   {
       return $this->name;

   }
}

$object= new myclass;
$object->setvalue("usman");
echo $object->getvalue();
?>
```

Thanks and Have a good one :)

Answer (score 1):

Final edit -

```
class myclass 
{
 var $name;

public function setvalue($newval)
{
   $this->name=$newval;      //variable calling was incorrect
}
public function getvalue()
{
   return $this->name;
}
}



$object= new myclass;    //class name correction
$object->setvalue("usman");
echo $object->getvalue();
```

Comment: thanks u and stackoverflow bidaway what was the issue

Comment: spelling mistake for class name and  ( $this->name ) right way to access class variables not this  ($this->$name). I hope my code is useful to be marked correct.